# Opening Added files pyinstaller .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created an .exe file that loads a GUI which has images in it. I added this image to the pyinstaller spec file :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['bot.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Victor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CS\\PythonProject\\Confessions'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[("logo.png", "logo.png"), ("template.jpg", "template.jpg")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='bot',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='logo_icon.ico')
```

and compiled the .exe. When I open the .exe it can't locate these files and closes. If I manually add the files to the directory where the .exe is located the .exe works normally.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the spec file, changing:

```
             datas=[("logo.png", "logo.png"), ("template.jpg", "template.jpg")],
```

to:

```
             datas=[("logo.png", "."), ("template.jpg", ".")],
```

worked as intended